# Error al realizar una consulta php PDO con postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, webservice, pdo

Buenas estoy tratando de realizar un web service con php y postgresql como base de datos, pero quiero que realizarlo por el metodo PDO y me ocurre errores.

```
<?php
require "database.class.php";
class Users
{

 private $con;
 public function __construct()
 {

 //en $this->con tenemos la conexión con la bd pruebas
 $this->con = new Database();

 }

 //obtenemos usuarios de una tabla con postgreSql
 public function getUsers()
 {

     try{

     $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT * FROM res_partner');
     $query->execute();
     $this->con->close_con();
     return $query->fetchAll();

     } catch(PDOException $e) {

             echo  $e->getMessage(); 

         }

 }

 Users::getUsers();

}
```

La conexion la establezco aqui

```
<?php
$host='------';
$db = 'DiiNLAB';
$username = 'odoo';
$password = '--';
```

[image: Imagen de error]

Comment: de donde es la ip, es de tu servidor remoto?

Comment: Es de un Vps...

Comment: Hay varios errores ciertamente. No puedes cerrar la conexión y luego intentar retornar algo relativo a ella como haces en `getUsers()`, puedes guardar los datos en una variable, luego cerrar y hacer el `return`, algo así: `$data=$query->fetchAll(); $this->con->close_con();
     return $data;` Luego `Users` no es una clase estática, ni `getUsers()` es un método estático, y aquí lo llamas como estático: `Users::getUsers();` Y más cosas que puede haber. Lo más conveniente sería que revises el log de errores para ver exactamente lo que está fallando.